# Verificar item checado

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho o seguinte codigo dentro do evento Itemchecked:

```
private void lsvRecebeGrupoLayout_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    Layout lay = new Layout();
    GrupoLayout grupo = new GrupoLayout();
    RepositorioGrupoLayout rgl = new RepositorioGrupoLayout();
    RepositorioLayout repolay = new RepositorioLayout();
    int idcbo = Convert.ToInt32(cboCarregaGrupo.SelectedValue);
    foreach (ListViewItem x in lsvRecebeGrupoLayout.CheckedItems)
    {
        int idlayout = Convert.ToInt32(x.SubItems[0].Text);
        lay = repolay.ConsultaPorId(idlayout);
        grupo.Id = idcbo;
        lay.GrupoLayout = grupo;

        if (x.Checked)
        {
            repolay.Alterar(lay);
        }       
    }
}
```

Quando a checkbox é clicada ela faz uma alteração no banco e se mantém marcada. Como eu poderia fazer para que quando o mesmo checkbox que foi clicado realize outra operação assim que ele receber outro click? Que removeria a marcação.

Comment: tentou usar o evento SelectedIndexChanged? Porque assim e possível verificar se o item foi marcado ou não caso tenha sido marcado executa esse trecho de código caso não.. faz o que você precisa.

Comment: Até tentei, porém quando instanciei o listview, ele diz que as checkbox dele são apenas para leitura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem a opçao de utilizar o ItemCheckedEventArgs referenciando o "e", assim você consegue acesso às propriedades do item que recebeu o clique:

```
e.Item.Checked;
e.Item.Index;
e.Item.Name;
```

Ou então você percorre todos os itens da ListView e seta o valor pra cada um

```
foreach(var i in listView1.Items)
{
   ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)i;
   SetValueInDatabase(listViewItem.Checked);
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar implementar na necessidade aqui. Obg Renan